# from list item object how to check is it a folder or not ? Using SharePoint Client Object Model C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, client-object-model

Have List item Obj. how to display it's item if it is a folder. using SharePoint Client Object Mode. here my code

```
            using (ClientContext ClientContext = new ClientContext(requestUrl))
        {
            List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestingFolder");
            clientContext.Load(docList); CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)

                Console.WriteLine(listItem.Id + "-"+ listItem["Title"]);


        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `FileSystemObjectType` property to determine if its folder or file Try below code:

```
using (ClientContext ClientContext = new ClientContext(requestUrl))
{
    List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestingFolder");
    context.Load(docList); 
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    context.Load(listItems);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Folder item " + listItem.Id + "-" + listItem["Title"]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File item " + listItem.Id + "-" + listItem["Title"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working need one more help .  I just want to display item count inside the each folder also what to do. ?

Answer (score 1):

Use  Folder property of the list item. This property will be null if the item is not a folder, so you can create a custom function like below:

```
public bool IsItemFolder(ListItem item)
{
    return item.Folder != null;
}
```